# what is the relationship between ruby, ruby on rails and html?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

what is the relationship between ruby, ruby on rails and html?

Answer (score 6):

[Ruby](http://www.ruby-lang.org/) is a [programming language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Programming_language). [Ruby on Rails](http://rubyonrails.org/) is a [Model-View-Controller](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Model_View_Controller) (MVC) [web application framework](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Web_application_framework) written in Ruby. [HTML](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTML) is a [markup language](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Markup_language) used for the formatting of web pages and is commonly used to present the output generated by a Ruby on Rails application to the final user.

Comment: More complete answer than mine

Answer (score 0):

Ruby is programming language

Ruby on rails is a web framework written in Ruby.

HTML is a markup language to create web pages

Answer (score 0):

HTML is markup language used majority of times in view of rails.It is used to design the frontend.
Ruby is a object oriented programming language with latest version as 1.9.2 and [Ruby on rails](http://guides.rubyonrails.org) built on ruby is a web application framework  with version3 currently in use.Links which may help you:
http://www.ruby-doc.org
http://api.rubyonrails.org